# How can I check if certain text-based content is being used somewhere else?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, content, text

I have ordered a blog article for my website, which has been written by someone else. Now I've received the text from the original author, but I'm a little bit concerned about if he has copied the content from other websites, which will have a quite negative SEO result for me.

My question is: How can I be sure, that he has not copied the ordered content from somewhere else? Is there some kind of tool or something? Thank you.

Comment: There are some tools around - search for "website plagiarism". Most are free and limited. We had a commercial one but decided to abandon it. To do it yourself, go through the text and choose some distinctive phrases, then search on Google/etc for them.

Comment: In addition to what @winwaed said, here are a bunch of search operators you can use to refine your searches: https://moz.com/learn/seo/search-operators

Comment: -----------------> `https://www.copyscape.com/` <-----------------

Comment: And again, in addition to what @winwaed mentioned with regards to searching Google. Wrap double quotes around the phrase to search for to enable an _exact match_, otherwise Google will search for the words contained in the phrase, not necessarily the phrase as a whole. eg. `"phrase to search for"`